# I get datatype, but what is the point of defining types in sml?

Tags: sml

It seems like defining types in SML isnt that helpful:

```
type point = int * int
val origin : point = (0, 0)
```

But I could easily just use `int * int` for typing methods, no? Compared with datatype, with which it seems you can do more interesting things like:

```
datatype Point = PlanePoint of (int * int) | SpacePoint of (int * int * int)
val origin : Point = SpacePoint(0, 0, 0)
```

Out of curiosity, what are situations where you really just gotta have a `type` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is mostly type safety. I will try to explain with a simple example.

Say you have a module that uses 2 types that are represented with `real * real`
For example, a 2d point like in your example, and a line represented by a slope and a y intercept. Now if you're writing a function like `lies_on_line` which takes a a point and a line and returns a boolean whether the point lies on the line you have 2 choices for a signature:

```
val lies_on_line : (int * int) * (int * int) -> bool
```

Ord

```
val lies_on_line : point * line -> bool
```

It's obvious that the 2nd example makes it harder to make mistakes.

Also, while it's more of a benefit for modules, naming a type allows you to change its representation without changing code that uses the type (indirectly through the module).

Comment: more good programming than absolutely necessary outside of modules then?

Comment: Yes, it's entirely optional. Personally I don't do it very often unless I plan on maybe changing the concrete type later. However, I use OCaml which also has labelled arguments which overlap in use and are more lightweight. It's mostly personal preference.

Comment: This seems wrong. Those two signatures are equivalent, so unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "type safety", none is provided here. The language allows something like `type myInt = int` `val x = 3 : myInt` `val y = x : int`. If you want a distinct signature, with compiler-enforced type safety and mistake prevention, you need to use a `datatype` as the OP suggested: `type myInt = MY_INT of int` `val x = MY_INT 3` `val MY_INT y = x`.

Comment: That's true you would have to make `point` and `line` abstract to achieve some type safety. I'm not that familiar with SML to remember how to do with that but with OCaml you would simply define `type point` and `type line` in the mli.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense to define aliases for your types in the context of your problem domain. That way you can think in your design in terms of more relevant and meaningful types.

For instance if you are writing a word processor program then you have types like:

```
type Word = string
type Sentence = Word list
```

which may make more sense than string and string list.